# Accessing other methods in a Ruby module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing my first Rails gem, which adds a method to ActiveRecord. I can't seem to figure out a simple way to call other methods from within the method I am adding to ActiveRecord. Is there a pattern for this I should be using?

```
module MyModule

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods

    def my_class_method
      # This doesn't work
      some_utility_method
    end

  end

  def some_utility_method
    # Do something useful
  end

end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, MyModule)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've included `MyModule`, `ActiveRecord::Base` will have `my_class_method` as a *class* method (equivalently, an instance method of the `Class` object `ActiveRecord::Base`), and `some_utility_method` as an *instance* method.

So, inside `my_class_method`, `self` is the *Class* `ActiveRecord::Base`, not an instance of that class; it does not have `some_utility_method` as an available method

**Edit:**
If you want a utility method private to the Module, you could do it like this:

```
module MyModule

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods

    def my_class_method
      # This doesn't work
      MyModule::some_utility_method
    end

  end

  def self.some_utility_method
    # Do something useful
  end

end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, MyModule)
```

Comment: That is what I thought. So... how does one utilize other methods in the module from the class method? I want to break up the functionality into smaller chunks, but only want to expose one class method to ActiveRecord.

Comment: @MattFordham - Ah, ok. Edited a solution in - how's that?